# Type hints for generic class union Callable

Tags: python, type-hinting

Given:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
class Factory(Generic[T]):
    def __call__(self) -> T:
        ...

class TruthyFactory(Factory[bool]):
    def __call__(self) -> bool:
        return True

def falsey_factory() -> bool:
    return False

def class_consumer(factory: type[Factory[T]]) -> T:
    ...

def function_consumer(factory: Callable[[], T]) -> T:
    ...

# type hint for cls_ret is `bool`
cls_ret = class_consumer(TruthyFactory)

# type hint for fn_ret is `bool`
fn_ret = function_consumer(falsey_factory)
```

What would the signature (type hints) look like for a function taking a unison of the two parameter types?

That is, a function signature of: `def either_consumer(factory: ???) -> T: ...`

I tried using `type[Factory[T]] | Callable[[], T]` but it not work with the type of a subclassed `Factory[T]`. The return type hint becomes the type of the class. I believe this is because a class matches the Callable specification - does this have higher affinity, is there a way of modifying this behaviour?

```py
def either_consumer(factory: type[Factory[T]] | Callable[[], T]) -> T:
    # needs more stringent boolean logic
    if isinstance(factory, type):
        return factory()()
    return factory()

# type hint for cls_ret is wrongly `TruthyFactory`
cls_ret = either_consumer(TruthyFactory)

# type hint for fn_ret is correctly `bool`
fn_ret = either_consumer(falsey_factory)
```

Comment: A type is a callable, so `factory: Callable[[], T]` should be sufficient.

Comment: I don’t want that behaviour, the are are two different mechanisms here one is ‘class_param()()’ the other is ‘fn_param()’. If there is a more clear way to describe the problem how should I phrase it? When I pass the _type_ of a subclass of a Factory[T] the return type should be T. I have updated the code example. I want the type hints to be correct for better developer experience in ide

Comment: Ah, right. The type *produces* a callable that returns a `T`. Honestly, I wouldn't do this in one function. Make the caller responsible for passing an instance `Factory` instead of making `either_consumer` have to call the factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found an answer (at least using pyright in vscode).

Setting the parameter type to `Callable[[], T] | type[Factory[T]]` works, however `type[Factory[T]] | Callable[[], T]` does not.

Additionally `type[Callable[[], T] | Factory[T]]` works.

I prefer the second option, but I do not know if this is entirely correct or it is undefined behaviour that just happens to work. I can not canonically say why... Perhaps the "type" of a function reference is its *signature* according to the type system?
The order of these parameters matters, I also assume type system matches the last matching type in the union?

The first option only works with `pyright`.
The second option works woth `pyright` and `jetbrains'`. I have not tested `mypy`.

Complete example:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
class Factory(Generic[T]):
    def __call__(self) -> T:
        ...

class TruthyFactory(Factory[bool]):
    def __call__(self) -> bool:
        return True

def falsey_factory() -> bool:
    return False

def either_consumer(factory: type[Callable[[], T] | Factory[T]]) -> T:
    # needs more stringent boolean logic
    if isinstance(factory, type):
        return factory()()
    return factory()

# type hint for cls_ret is correctly `bool`
cls_ret = either_consumer(TruthyFactory)

# type hint for fn_ret is correctly `bool`
fn_ret = either_consumer(falsey_factory)
```

Rearranging @chepner's answer works also but is unconstrained `Callable[[], T | Callable[[], T]]`

On more experimenting it seems this is inconsistent entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would recommend actually doing this, but consider that `Factory` is a callable that takes no arguments and returns a callable that takes no arguments and returns a `T`. That means you can write a union like

```
Callable[[], Callable[[], T]] | Callable[[], T]
```

for the argument type. A little type algebra lets you refactor this as

```
Callable[[], Callable[[], T] | T]
```

since both "outer" callables take no arguments. When you call `factory`, you'll either have the desired boolean, or a callable to call again to get a boolean.

```
def either_consumer(factory: Callable[[], Callable[[], T] | T]) -> T:
    rv = factory()
    if isinstance(rv, bool):
        return rv
    return rv()
```

---

I would prefer making `consumer` take strictly a `Callable[[], T]`, and let the *caller* be responsible for instantiating a factory class to get an object with type `Callable[[], T]` instead.

```
FactoryType = Callable[[], T]

def consumer(f: FactoryType[T]) -> T
    ...

consumer(TruthyFactory())
consumer(falsey_factory)
```

Comment: Switching the union works `Callable[[], T | Callable[[], T]]`. I found a workaround though to constrain it to `FactoryType[T]` or `Callable[[], T]`, I'll post the answer